# How would i know the given url is restfull url or json in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I want to know my url is rest or json,when i see.And how to provide security to rest and json services in ios.

Comment: `Content-Type` will tell you, if its `application/json` its json else you know.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "rest" and "json" urls or how you think those represent different things. Asking "how to provide security" is far too broad to receive a useful answer.

Comment: rest or json both are different thing :)

Comment: REST is a type of webservice and json is result of that service.